# Trying to get a error for a function

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python

I made a login UI to connect python with sql, using MySQLdb as the module for it.
The UI work fine it pops up and does it thing the login data are stored in a class for that session.

BUT if you put in wrong login data the program will try to connect but fails which returns an error like this

```
Error: OperationalError: file C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py line 187: 2005
```

I need an if else command to check if there is a connection to the server. Right now it just trys to connect and goes on to the next function. which work fine when the login data is right. but will be meaningless if the login data is wrong since it will still try to get data from MySQL with the wrong login and will return nothing.

Comment: This is a little unclear. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Can you show us the code to see where's the error ?

Comment: `import MySQLdb`
`    def login ():`
`   db = MySQLdb.connect( host=hostinfo, user=userinfo, passwd=passwdinfo, db=dbinfo)`
`    main()`    
    
`    def main ():`
`    themain function`
       
this is basicaly the command which connects to mysql which right now after its done just jumps to the main function.
i want to stop it from doing main if it returns an error like the one i state

Comment: `OperationalError` is an exception, so it's raised, not returned, and you should be able to catch and handle the exception. Please edit your post with the relevant part of your code.

Comment: yes sry this is my first post here and. i tryed to post the relevant part of the post with right spacing but it does's do it.

Comment: `import MySQLdb
    def login ():
    db = MySQLdb.connect( host=hostinfo, user=userinfo, passwd=passwdinfo, db=dbinfo)
    main()  
    
    def main ():
    themain function

`